# CSURF Angular Implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, csrf

I have been trying to do a csurf implementation on a personal project I have been working on. I have been searching google all over the place to try to figure out how to implement csurf on a form when I am not using a templating engine like Jade or EJS. My express server is also not directly rendering the pages but is mainly returning JSON. I have all of my front end being referenced like so

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
```

my server code that is using the csurf looks like this

```
app.use(csurf());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
```

On the front end for the form the html input field looks like this. I am also using AngularJS and based on examples I have seen all I should have to do is this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrftoken}}">
```

I am getting the following error in the terminal

```
Error: invalid csrf token
```

If I inspect the hidden input this is what is displayed.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="">
```

Comment: This looks correct. What exactly is the issue/error that you're seeing?

Comment: When you inspect the dom, do you actually see a hash set to the value attribute? Pasting the results of that will help immensely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, you need to set a local variable to equal the value of the csrf cookie

e.g.

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function($cookies, $scope) {
    $scope.csrftoken = $cookies._csrf
  }
);
```

For that example to work you will need to include the ngCookies module, so include something like this in your index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

And then add the dependency 'ngCookies' to your module.

Answer (score 3):

According to section "**Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection**" of `$http` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#):

> When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN).

So, you need just to configure `csurf` module to use that cookie. Like that:

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
...
// Cookie / Session initialization etc
app.use(cookieParser());
...
// Important : csrf should be added after cookie and session initialization.
// Otherwise you will get 'Error: misconfigured csrf'
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
...
```

Doing so, you don't need to configure your AngularJS stuff and create hidden inputs.